# Should Twitter's official clients invert the scroll direction on some screens?

Tags: scrolling

Twitter's official clients on some platforms (iOS, OSX) invert the scroll direction when reading DMs and @replies from a specific person. Is this the best UX in your opinion, or is it just confusing? How should it work?

When reading public tweets, or looking at a list of people who have DM or replied to you, the latest message appears at the top. This model is followed on the Twitter website for DMs and @replies.

On iOS and OSX, when viewing the most recent DMs or @replies from a specific person the latest message appears at the bottom. This differs from the rest of the UI but *is* familiar from IRC/IM/whatever chat: read top to bottom.

I can understand the arguments for both approaches, but for me it seems like there's a disconnect in the interface when the approach is inverted dependent on platform [1] and app screen.

Discuss :)

<sub>[1] I don't know how Twitter behaves on other platforms, but on my Android device's client (presumably official because it has a proper Twitter logo), @replies and DMs are latest-at-top.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its good UI but bad UX.

When you are reading DM it makes sense to have them on the bottom. However, the DM page is part of a larger app and as UX goes the users will be confused. It's so easy to forget we are not designing for ourselves. I have to remind myself daily.

Comment: Thanks - your reply has at least helped me understand the difference between UI and UX :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's terrible and it confuses me every time. It's a glaring violation of internal consistency principles.

Answer (score 1):

I've always wished this behavior was configurable. But since @replies do function like most email clients, so I think the current implementation works.